# Why are there 2 places to set session.cookie_lifetime in php.ini

Tags: configuration, php

I am finding 2 places where session.cookie_lifetime is set.

Here:

```
; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
session.cookie_lifetime = 36000
```

and here

```
; Document expires after n minutes.
session.cookie_lifetime = 36000
```

Do they both have to be the same value? Why is this set in two places? It is pretty confusing the way it is.

Comment: I have in only one line in `php.ini`.

Comment: I think the latter should rather be session.cache_expire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The default php.ini](http://www.reallylinux.com/docs/php.ini) does *not* contain two of these directives.

Something has added the second to your INI file. It overrides the first, making the first redundant.

Comment: Yeah I accidentally  overwrote the session.cache_expire variable.  Oops :)

Answer (score 2):

There should only be a single session.cookie_lietime value set, not two.

I looked through my own php.ini and I found this line:

```
; Document expires after n minutes.
; http://php.net/session.cache-expire
session.cache_expire = 180
```

I'm assuming that the second session.cookie_lifetime is either misspelt in your config file or you misread. The session cache expiry and the cookie lifetime are two different things.

Have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime and https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-expire.